# How to create a search function of a list with multiple organized elements?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function with two inputs (number, people) whereas it searches from a list with multiple organized elements for the correct number and outputs the correct information (which the output is named: user).

**Here's the list:**

```
List = ([15209 Amanda Craig NC], [16428 Johnathan Smith OH], [12690 Samantha Owens IL], [17002 Mark Stenson NY], [13379 Francis Trent NC], [14904 Jake Peterson CA])
```

**The number request (not a user-input):**

```
14904
17002
19999
```

**Desired output:**

```
14904 Jake Peterson CA
17002 Mark Stenson NY
"User not found"
```

This is what I have at the moment. I'm not sure if I should use split, but then I have no clue what to do next.

```
people = ([15209 Amanda Craig NC], [16428 Johnathan Smith OH], [12690 Samantha Owens IL], [17002 Mark Stenson NY], [13379 Francis Trent NC], [14904 Jake Peterson CA])

user = people[i]

def search_user(number, people):
    ID = people.split()[0]
    if number != ID: #I'm not sure how I can find the numbers 
        return "User not found"
    else:
        return user
```

If anything is wrong, it is okay to scrap it. I'm a bit confused about where to even start.

Comment: Your definition of `users` is not valid Python syntax. Can you edit your question and fix this?

Comment: Sure. I'm sorry, I'll change it to something else.

Comment: No, it is a list. I haven't learned yet about tupples.

Comment: It is lists inside the `Tupple` ..correct me anyone if I'm wrong

Comment: Hey there, welcome to StackOverflow. Users are defined in a way that will make it hard and expensive to search through in the long run. Instead of finding a solution to this problem, I suggest you concentrate on making the user list more readable, and accessible, which in turn will make the solution easier as well. Check out my answer for a solution proposal.

Comment: @Learningonestepatatime `[15209 Amanda Craig NC]` isn't a valid expression. It could be `["15209 Amanda Craig NC"]` or `["15209", "Amanda", "Craig", "NC"]` or `[15209, "Amanda", "Craig", "NC"]` or even `"15209 Amanda Craig NC"`. Next time please make sure that we don't have to guess what your data structure really loks like. The answer will be different for all those cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you insist on using a Tuple of lists, you should fix the syntax as was advised, which could lead for example to:

```
users = ([15209, "Amanda Craig NC"], [16428, "Johnathan Smith OH"], [12690, "Samantha Owens IL"], [17002, "Mark Stenson NY"], [13379, "Francis Trent NC"], [14904, "Jake Peterson CA"])

def search_user(number, users):
    for user in users:
        if user[0] == number:
            return user
    return "User not found"
            
            
print(search_user(14904, users))
print(search_user(17002, users))
print(search_user(19999, users))
```

That said, a dictionary would be far more relevant to your needs, as per the previous answer.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it (only thing I changed was user.split[0]) and it worked exactly as I wanted.

Comment: You're welcome. good luck on your assignments :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're not married to the idea of having users in a Tuple containing lists, I suggest you work on making your data more easily available, to avoid looping over the user list.

Ideally, it would be a dictionary, where key would be the "id" and value the name of the person.

Working example:

```
from typing import Dict

users: Dict = {
    15209: "Amanda Craig NC",
    16428: "Johnathan Smith OH",
    12690: "Samantha Owens IL",
}


def get_user_by_id(user_id: int) -> str:
    return users.get(user_id, "Unknown User")


user: str = get_user_by_id(15209)
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Yes, you are absolutely right! This is part of an assignment that I’ve been trying for some time (a week) for an elective course in my university. The list is actually part of two previous exercises (both of them in my previous asked question in SO), which ends full circle with this one, which is the last exercise of the assignment. Honestly, I feel like me (and the rest of the students) were thrown a bit to the crocodiles, since I’m having a lot of difficulties with this assignment, and it’s only the second one out of 5 of this semester. I don’t know what is Dict

Comment: Also, thank you, and everyone else, for the help. It’s been hard, but I’m learning on small steps

Comment: I wish you all the best in Uni, one step at a time, as your username already says :) To answer what is Dict, check python's 'type hinting'. It will make your code more readable and easier to understand down the line. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the formatting of the list entries has, reliably, the ID in first position:

```
def search_user(number, users):
    for user in users:
        if number == int(users.split()[0]):
            return user
    return "User not found"
```